# React state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Playing with react, trying to build a simple chat app that will be connected to firebase.

I have one container - ChatApp - and one component UserInput.

ChatApp ->

```
import React from 'react';
import UserInput from '../components/UserInput';

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            chatting: false
        };
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <UserInput
                startChat={this.chatCanStart}
            />
        </div>;
    },
    chatCanStart: function(recipient) {
        console.log(recipient);
        this.setState({
            chatting: true
        })
    }
});
```

UserInput ->

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            username: '',
            recipient: 'asgasg'
        };
    },
    handleUsernameChange: function(event) {
        let text = event.target.text;
        this.setState({
            username: text
        });
    },
    handleRecipientChange: function(event) {
        let text = event.target.text;
        this.setState({
            recipient: text
        });
    },
    handleStartChat: function() {
        if (this.state.username !== '' && this.state.recipient !== ''){
            console.log(this.state.recipient);
            this.props.startChat(this.state.recipient);
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div className="panel panel-default">
            <div className="panel-heading"> Welcome to the chat app done in React </div>
            <div className="panel-body">
                <div className="input-group">
                    <span className="input-group-addon"> Username </span>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange} />
                </div>
                <br />
                <div className="input-group">
                    <span className="input-group-addon"> Recipient </span>
                    <input type="email" className="form-control" value={this.state.recipient} onChange={this.handleRecipientChange} />
                </div>
                <br />
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleStartChat}> Chat now </button>
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

When I change the Username and Recipient fields and then click on the Chat now button, I am expecting the chatting state in the ChatApp container to change to true and also want to log the passed recipient.

But I get 'undefined', why is that? I get 'undefined' even in the console.log in the UserInput component. Even though the inputs value in the form is being changed just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get value from input you need to use `.value` property instead of `.text`

```
handleUsernameChange: function(event) {
  let text = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    username: text
  });
},

handleRecipientChange: function(event) {
  let text = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    recipient: text
  });
},
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/31253/)